# Get all posts with a certain meta key, except for one with specific title

Tags: get-posts, meta-query

I need to return all posts with `post_test_safe == 1` and exclude one with `title ="Special title"`

Some kind of combined meta query but haven't got anything to work.

```
function getAllPostIdsTest(){
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post_test',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_test_safe',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => 'EQUALS'
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'asc'
    );
    $ids = get_posts( $args );
    send_json($ids);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unable to test this at the moment, but try something along these lines. Search all posts for your Post Name (*Special title*), grabbing the ID's, then utilize `post__not_in` to exclude those IDs in `get_posts`.

```
function getAllPostIdsTest(){

     global $wpdb;
     $excluded_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%"Special title"%' && `post_type` = 'post_test'");

     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post_test',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_test_safe',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'asc',
        'post__not_in' => $excluded_posts
    );

    $ids = get_posts( $args );
    send_json($ids);

}
```

Edit: `post__not_in` is expecting a simple array of ID's, ex// `array(1,2,3,4)`